# Ember: Programmatically set queryParams in Mixin

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to programmatically define queryParams in an Ember.Mixin.

The mixin has a method which is called when the controller holding the mixin is initialized.

```
setupQueryParams: (params) ->
  params.forEach (param) =>
    @get('queryParams').push(param)
```

Later in an action defined on the mixin I call `@transitionToRoute({queryParams: {someParam: 'something'}})` nothing happens. However when I explicitly define my queryParams, this works.

Comment: Did you ever find a way around this? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`queryParams` are resolved off the proto of the class, not an instance, so any `init` functionality wouldn't be applied in time for ember to resolve it.

This just means late binding of the `queryParams` isn't possible in the way you want.

Comment: Are there any established patterns for hooking into `extend`? I'm envisioning a hook like `wasMixedIn`...

Comment: Did you ever find a way around this? I'm experiencing the same issue.